# Ajax & JavaScript Multiple Select onchange failing after 3 selected items

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have a select input with the following code:

```
<select name="color" id="color" multiple class="form-control chzn-select" tabindex="8" onchange="autosave(this.id,this.value)">
```

It is successfully sending the function ID and select value, but seeing as one can select multiple items, it's having an issue. I can select up to 3 items without a problem, but attempting to select a 4th is causing it to pass the value of the first selected item. Not the most recently selected item. Here's the function, which sends other information such as title and date (both text inputs):

```
function autosave(inputid,values) {
var dataObj = {};
dataObj[inputid] = values;
  $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "save.php",
      data: dataObj,
      success: function(msg) {
          $('#autosavenotify').text(msg);
          console.log('success');
      }
  })
}
```

HTML wise I am using Bootstrap3 if that makes a difference and here's how I'm populating the select options:

```
<?php
$colors = array('Red','Blue','Yellow','Purple','Green','Orange');
foreach($colors as $c) {
    $selected = '';

    if(in_array($c, $_SESSION['array']['colors'])) {
        $selected = 'selected';
    }

    echo '<option value="'.$c.'" '.$selected.'>'.$c.'</option>';
}
?>
```

Any ideas why this might be happening? My save.php page is placing all items successfully within the array, the ajax is just sending the incorrect value for some reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you're already using jQuery, you'd probably be better off just using `$(this).val( )` to get the selected options from your select.  Here's a fiddle I came up with using your provided code: http://jsfiddle.net/y7NfF/1/

Another route you might consider taking would be using jQuery's `.serialize()` or `.serializeArray()` function to get all values of your form when submitting the data through ajax.  However, if you want to do one element at a time, your method works just fine.

Here are a couple of links to those functions:

http://api.jquery.com/serialize/

http://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/

Comment: I threw that in a few times but obviously not in the right place. Thanks!